# Реализация кроссдоменной авторизации

Tags: php, javascript, авторизация, cross-domain

Есть сайт **service.com**, выступающий в качестве точки авторизации для сайта **mydomain.com**.

При авторизации `sessionID` записывается в БД, на сайте **service.com** ставится кука с флагом авторизации и случайным идентификатором этой куки.

Задача - получить авторизацию для **mydomain.com**, т.е. запросить куку с **service.com** со значением флага авторизации. Если флаг установлен, из БД запрашивается `sessionID`, после чего на **mydomain.com** запускается `session_start(sessionID)`.

Значение куки планирую получить с помощью [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain).

Вопрос: позволяет ли `XMLHttpRequest` прозрачно, т.е. без действий пользователя установить куку, или он может лишь *передать значение* этой куки? Насколько я понимаю, только передать значение. Но тогда вопрос: как передать полученные значения флага авторизации и идентификатора куки в php-скрипт, чтобы по полученному идентификатору запросить `sessionID` из БД?

`Js` будет вставлен в `header`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/get_cookie.js"></script>
</head>
```

Может быть я вообще неправильно подхожу к решению задачи, прошу подсказать правильный путь.

**UPD.**

Необходима не просто авторизация *на* или *с помощью* стороннего ресурса, но сквозная авторизация вида **Single Sign-On** для всех сайтов, для которых service.com выступает в качестве точки авторизации. Т.е. авторизовавшись на одном сайте, нужно автоматически сохранять авторизацию на каждом сайте.

Answer (score 2):

Для кросдоменной авторизации лучше организовать её по протоколу OAuth 2.0. При этом клиенты с других доменов будут ходить за авторизацией на service.com.

[OAuth 2.0 простым и понятным языком](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/115163/)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Внес уточнение в вопрос: нужна именно сквозная авторизация вида Single Sign-On для всех сайтов, для которых service.com выступает в качестве точки авторизации. Т.е. авторизовавшись на одном сайте, нужно автоматически сохранять авторизацию на каждом сайте. OAuth 2.0 для этого не подойдет, насколько я понял принцип его работы.